# Let $S$ be a semigroup. If for any $x,y\in S$, $x^2y=y=yx^2$, then prove that $S$ is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup. If for any $x,y\in S$, $x^2y=y=yx^2$, then prove that $S$ is an abelian group.

My solution goes like this:

> If for any $x,y\in S$, we have $x^2y=y=yx^2$. Then this implies $x^2=e$. So, $x=x^{-1}$ and this holds $\forall x\in S$. Hence, if $a,b\in S$ then $(a\cdot b)\in S$ and $$(a\cdot b)=(a\cdot b)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba.$$ Thus, $S$ is an abelian group.

Is the above solution correct? Is it valid? If not, then where does it go wrong?

Comment: You need to work on your punctuation, @Franklin. Far too many times in your recent posts, your punctuation marks are a space away from the end of a clause or there's no space at all.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1189739/104041)

Comment: There is no need to introduce the $\cdot$ symbol.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: This is a [tag:solution-verification] question, @CameronBuie, so no, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your supposed proof assumes that there is an identity in the semigroup, which isn't always a given; you have to show it. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1189739/104041) for a real proof.

Comment: It is possible that the OP meant that the given condition amounts to saying any $x^2$ is a two-sided identity.

Comment: If that was intended, @hardmath, then the OP should have said so explicitly. But it's a good point. Thank you :)